Xdebug 3.3.x no longer triggering on breakpoint in symlink'ed file of PhpStorm project
I have a local WAMP stack with Xdebug 3.2 that I have been using with a PhpStorm project (PHP, Joomla) where some of the folders of the Joomla directory are symlink'ed to my own development directories. In the project settings I have a simple "PHP -> Server" setting of the local server host and the 'Use path mappings' is unchecked. This has been working fine in multiple instances for many years. I can set and trigger breakpoints in both regular and symlink'ed files and directories.
I have tried to update the WAMP, and tried other WAMPs, and I have narrowed it down to any change from Xdebug 3.2 to 3.3.0 or above will not cause breakpoints in the symlink'ed files to be triggered and instead I get a 'Debug session finished without being paused message' and to check the set up and path mapping. 'Break at first line' and any breakpoints in non-symlink'ed files and directories are triggered as expected so Xdebug is getting invoked.
I have been trying numerous combinations of settings in the 'Use mappings' and the 'Deployment' settings of PhpStorm but to no avail, symlink'ed files are not triggered. Without changing anything in PhpStorm, just returning to Xdebug 3.2 and the breakpoints are now triggered as expected.
I have compared debug.log for both 3.2 and 3.3.x doing the exact same process and I can see the breakpoints are defined and the same in both versions but in 3.3.x you can see that the line in the symlink'ed file never gets a triggered action.
Xdebug settings in shown in phpinfo() are the same. In php.ini I have these settings and change the module name to anything with 3.3.x in it and the problem appears:
zend_extension=php_xdebug-3.2.2-8.1-vs16-x86_64.dll
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.log = D:\temp\xdebug_3.2.log

I have been going around in circles for days now and haven't been able to find any similar sort of issue or suggestion that can get me across to a working Xdebug 3.3.0 environment.
*** Update 16/07/2024 ***
I have tried to simplify the diagnosing of this issue and have tested with this minimal settings in php.ini. Simply by un-commenting I can switch between xdebug modules to go from working to not working environments.
[xdebug]
;zend_extension=php_xdebug-3.2.2-8.1-vs16-x86_64.dll
zend_extension=php_xdebug-3.3.1-8.1-vs16-x86_64.dll
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes

My test approach has been to add two breakpoints into a file. One breakpoint is set in the project file, the source of the symlink, and the second breakpoint at a different line # in to the same file in from the execution environment. When it works both breakpoints are triggered and when it doesn't only the second breakpoint is triggered.
As a test I set up a simple test php file that allowed me to set the two breakpoints.
<?php

$name = "fred";
echo $name;

Unexpectedly both breakpoints were triggered on both xdebug 3.2 and xdebug 3.3 environments.
I then set two breakpoints in the Joomla cli environment, to avoid the use of a  http server environment, and when running the xdebug 3.3 environment the project file breakpoint was not triggered which is the behaviour I am seeing. When using xdebug 3.2 both breakpoints were triggered.
I have the debug.log from each run, xdebug 3.2. and xdebug 3.3, where both breakpoints are set but only one is triggered in 3.3. I have trimmed out the unrelated lines of each file to keep them short to paste here.
xdebug_3.2.log
[22956] Log opened at 2024-07-16 08:36:57.995859
[22956] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9003.
[22956] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).
[22956] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///E:/www/Emu/cli/joomla.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="8.1.10" protocol_version="1.0" appid="22956"><engine version="3.2.2"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2023 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[22956] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 1 -n show_hidden -v 1
[22956] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>

[22956] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 2 -n max_depth -v 1
[22956] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>

[22956] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 3 -n max_children -v 100
[22956] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

[22956] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 4 -n extended_properties -v 1
[22956] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="4" feature="extended_properties" success="1"></response>

[22956] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 5 -n notify_ok -v 1
[22956] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="5" feature="notify_ok" success="1"></response>

[22956] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 6 -n resolved_breakpoints -v 1
[22956] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="6" feature="resolved_breakpoints" success="1"></response>

[22956] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 7 -n breakpoint_include_return_value -v 1
[22956] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="7" feature="breakpoint_include_return_value" success="1"></response>

[22956] [Step Debug] <- stdout -i 8 -c 1
[22956] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stdout" transaction_id="8" success="1"></response>

[22956] [Step Debug] <- status -i 9
[22956] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="status" transaction_id="9" status="starting" reason="ok"></response>

[22956] [Step Debug] <- step_into -i 10
[22956] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="10" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///E:/www/Emu/cli/joomla.php" lineno="12"></xdebug:message></response>

[22956] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 11 -- Z2V0ZW52KCdQSFBfSURFX0NPTkZJRycpIT1mYWxzZQ==
[22956] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="11"><property type="bool"><![CDATA[0]]></property></response>

[22956] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 12 -- aXNzZXQoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NFUlZFUl9OQU1FJ10p
[22956] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="12"><property type="bool"><![CDATA[0]]></property></response>

[22956] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 13 -- aXNzZXQoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NTSF9DT05ORUNUSU9OJ10p
[22956] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="13"><property type="bool"><![CDATA[0]]></property></response>

[22956] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 14 -- aXNzZXQoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NFUlZFUl9BRERSJ10p
[22956] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="14"><property type="bool"><![CDATA[0]]></property></response>

[22956] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 15 -t line -f file://E:/repositories/LL_inventory2/plugins/console/inventoryll/src/Emptydata.php -n 100
[22956] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="15" id="229560001" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[22956] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 16 -t line -f file://E:/www/Emu/plugins/console/inventoryll/src/Emptydata.php -n 113
[22956] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="16" id="229560002" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[22956] [Step Debug] <- stack_get -i 17
[22956] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="17"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///E:/www/Emu/cli/joomla.php" lineno="12"></stack></response>

.....   Unrelated messages

[22956] [Step Debug] -> <notify xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" name="breakpoint_resolved"><breakpoint type="line" resolved="resolved" filename="file:///e:/repositories/LL_inventory2/plugins/console/inventoryll/src/Emptydata.php" lineno="113" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="229560002"></breakpoint></notify>

.....  Unrelated messages

[22956] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="18" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///e:/repositories/LL_inventory2/plugins/console/inventoryll/src/Emptydata.php" lineno="100"></xdebug:message></response>

[22956] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 19 -- JEdMT0JBTFNbJ0lERV9FVkFMX0NBQ0hFJ11bJ2YzMmMwNWI2LWZhMzEtNGIyMC1hMzA3LTZmNzVmMWE4NjBiZiddPWVycm9yX3JlcG9ydGluZygpOw==
[22956] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="19"><property type="int"><![CDATA[32767]]></property></response>

..... Repeats 20 to 73 with similar 
 
[22956] [Step Debug] <- stack_get -i 74
[22956] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="74"><stack where="Irata\Plugin\Console\Inventoryll\Emptydata-&gt;doExecute" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///e:/repositories/LL_inventory2/plugins/console/inventoryll/src/Emptydata.php" lineno="100"></stack><stack where="Joomla\Console\Command\AbstractCommand-&gt;execute" level="1" type="file" filename="file:///E:/www/Emu/libraries/vendor/joomla/console/src/Command/AbstractCommand.php" lineno="235"></stack><stack where="Joomla\Console\Application-&gt;runCommand" level="2" type="file" filename="file:///E:/www/Emu/libraries/vendor/joomla/console/src/Application.php" lineno="1181"></stack><stack where="Joomla\Console\Application-&gt;doExecute" level="3" type="file" filename="file:///E:/www/Emu/libraries/vendor/joomla/console/src/Application.php" lineno="403"></stack><stack where="Joomla\CMS\Application\ConsoleApplication-&gt;doExecute" level="4" type="file" filename="file:///E:/www/Emu/libraries/src/Application/ConsoleApplication.php" lineno="205"></stack><stack where="Joomla\Console\Application-&gt;execute" level="5" type="file" filename="file:///E:/www/Emu/libraries/vendor/joomla/console/src/Application.php" lineno="448"></stack><stack where="Joomla\CMS\Application\ConsoleApplication-&gt;execute" level="6" type="file" filename="file:///E:/www/Emu/libraries/src/Application/ConsoleApplication.php" lineno="258"></stack><stack where="{main}" level="7" type="file" filename="file:///E:/www/Emu/cli/joomla.php" lineno="77"></stack></response>

......

[22956] [Step Debug] <- stack_get -i 81
[22956] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="81"><stack where="Irata\Plugin\Console\Inventoryll\Emptydata-&gt;doExecute" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///e:/repositories/LL_inventory2/plugins/console/inventoryll/src/Emptydata.php" lineno="113"></stack><stack where="Joomla\Console\Command\AbstractCommand-&gt;execute" level="1" type="file" filename="file:///E:/www/Emu/libraries/vendor/joomla/console/src/Command/AbstractCommand.php" lineno="235"></stack><stack where="Joomla\Console\Application-&gt;runCommand" level="2" type="file" filename="file:///E:/www/Emu/libraries/vendor/joomla/console/src/Application.php" lineno="1181"></stack><stack where="Joomla\Console\Application-&gt;doExecute" level="3" type="file" filename="file:///E:/www/Emu/libraries/vendor/joomla/console/src/Application.php" lineno="403"></stack><stack where="Joomla\CMS\Application\ConsoleApplication-&gt;doExecute" level="4" type="file" filename="file:///E:/www/Emu/libraries/src/Application/ConsoleApplication.php" lineno="205"></stack><stack where="Joomla\Console\Application-&gt;execute" level="5" type="file" filename="file:///E:/www/Emu/libraries/vendor/joomla/console/src/Application.php" lineno="448"></stack><stack where="Joomla\CMS\Application\ConsoleApplication-&gt;execute" level="6" type="file" filename="file:///E:/www/Emu/libraries/src/Application/ConsoleApplication.php" lineno="258"></stack><stack where="{main}" level="7" type="file" filename="file:///E:/www/Emu/cli/joomla.php" lineno="77"></stack></response>

..... 

[22956] [Step Debug] <- run -i 86
[22956] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="86" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[22956] [Step Debug] <- detach -i 87
[22956] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="detach" transaction_id="87" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[22956] Log closed at 2024-07-16 08:37:01.893239

The failing run
xdebug_3.3.log
[32988] Log opened at 2024-07-16 08:54:54.221348
[32988] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9003.
[32988] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).
[32988] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///E:/www/Emu/cli/joomla.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="8.1.10" protocol_version="1.0" appid="32988"><engine version="3.3.1"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2023 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[32988] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 1 -n show_hidden -v 1
[32988] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>

[32988] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 2 -n max_depth -v 1
[32988] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>

[32988] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 3 -n max_children -v 100
[32988] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

[32988] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 4 -n extended_properties -v 1
[32988] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="4" feature="extended_properties" success="1"></response>

[32988] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 5 -n notify_ok -v 1
[32988] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="5" feature="notify_ok" success="1"></response>

[32988] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 6 -n resolved_breakpoints -v 1
[32988] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="6" feature="resolved_breakpoints" success="1"></response>

[32988] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 7 -n breakpoint_include_return_value -v 1
[32988] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="7" feature="breakpoint_include_return_value" success="1"></response>

[32988] [Step Debug] <- stdout -i 8 -c 1
[32988] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stdout" transaction_id="8" success="1"></response>

[32988] [Step Debug] <- status -i 9
[32988] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="status" transaction_id="9" status="starting" reason="ok"></response>

[32988] [Step Debug] <- step_into -i 10
[32988] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="10" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///E:/www/Emu/cli/joomla.php" lineno="12"></xdebug:message></response>

[32988] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 11 -- Z2V0ZW52KCdQSFBfSURFX0NPTkZJRycpIT1mYWxzZQ==
[32988] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="11"><property type="bool"><![CDATA[0]]></property></response>

[32988] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 12 -- aXNzZXQoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NFUlZFUl9OQU1FJ10p
[32988] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="12"><property type="bool"><![CDATA[0]]></property></response>

[32988] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 13 -- aXNzZXQoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NTSF9DT05ORUNUSU9OJ10p
[32988] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="13"><property type="bool"><![CDATA[0]]></property></response>

[32988] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 14 -- aXNzZXQoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NFUlZFUl9BRERSJ10p
[32988] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="14"><property type="bool"><![CDATA[0]]></property></response>

[32988] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 15 -t line -f file://E:/repositories/LL_inventory2/plugins/console/inventoryll/src/Emptydata.php -n 100
[32988] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="15" id="329880001" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[32988] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 16 -t line -f file://E:/www/Emu/plugins/console/inventoryll/src/Emptydata.php -n 113
[32988] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="16" id="329880002" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[32988] [Step Debug] <- stack_get -i 17
[32988] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="17"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///E:/www/Emu/cli/joomla.php" lineno="12"></stack></response>

.....   Unrelated messages

[32988] [Step Debug] -> <notify xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" name="breakpoint_resolved"><breakpoint type="line" resolved="resolved" filename="file:///e:/repositories/LL_inventory2/plugins/console/inventoryll/src/Emptydata.php" lineno="113" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="329880002"></breakpoint></notify>

.....   

[32988] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="18" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///e:/repositories/LL_inventory2/plugins/console/inventoryll/src/Emptydata.php" lineno="113"></xdebug:message></response>

[32988] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 19 -- JEdMT0JBTFNbJ0lERV9FVkFMX0NBQ0hFJ11bJzVkMmE1Yjc3LWExYWItNGE0YS04MTMyLWZkODg0ZjljOWVjNiddPWVycm9yX3JlcG9ydGluZygpOw==
[32988] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="19"><property type="int"><![CDATA[32767]]></property></response>

.....  Repeats 20 to 72 with similar

[32988] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 73 -- JEdMT0JBTFNbJ0lERV9FVkFMX0NBQ0hFJ11bJ2ZjMjNjZDUzLTMzNDYtNDA1NS05YzIyLWY2NjExMDZkNGM2OSddPWVycm9yX3JlcG9ydGluZygpOw==
[32988] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="73"><property type="int"><![CDATA[32767]]></property></response>

[32988] [Step Debug] <- stack_get -i 74
[32988] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="74"><stack where="Irata\Plugin\Console\Inventoryll\Emptydata-&gt;doExecute" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///e:/repositories/LL_inventory2/plugins/console/inventoryll/src/Emptydata.php" lineno="113"></stack><stack where="Joomla\Console\Command\AbstractCommand-&gt;execute" level="1" type="file" filename="file:///E:/www/Emu/libraries/vendor/joomla/console/src/Command/AbstractCommand.php" lineno="235"></stack><stack where="Joomla\Console\Application-&gt;runCommand" level="2" type="file" filename="file:///E:/www/Emu/libraries/vendor/joomla/console/src/Application.php" lineno="1181"></stack><stack where="Joomla\Console\Application-&gt;doExecute" level="3" type="file" filename="file:///E:/www/Emu/libraries/vendor/joomla/console/src/Application.php" lineno="403"></stack><stack where="Joomla\CMS\Application\ConsoleApplication-&gt;doExecute" level="4" type="file" filename="file:///E:/www/Emu/libraries/src/Application/ConsoleApplication.php" lineno="205"></stack><stack where="Joomla\Console\Application-&gt;execute" level="5" type="file" filename="file:///E:/www/Emu/libraries/vendor/joomla/console/src/Application.php" lineno="448"></stack><stack where="Joomla\CMS\Application\ConsoleApplication-&gt;execute" level="6" type="file" filename="file:///E:/www/Emu/libraries/src/Application/ConsoleApplication.php" lineno="258"></stack><stack where="{main}" level="7" type="file" filename="file:///E:/www/Emu/cli/joomla.php" lineno="77"></stack></response>

[32988] [Step Debug] <- context_names -i 75
[32988] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_names" transaction_id="75"><context name="Locals" id="0"></context><context name="Superglobals" id="1"></context><context name="User defined constants" id="2"></context></response>

..... 

[32988] [Step Debug] <- run -i 80
[32988] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="80" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[32988] [Step Debug] <- detach -i 81
[32988] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="detach" transaction_id="81" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[32988] Log closed at 2024-07-16 08:54:56.486104

In the output the breakpoint at line 100 is set in the project source file, the source of the symlink, in e:/repositories/LL_inventory2.
The breakpoint at line 113 in set in the execution environment, the Joomla instance, of the same file.

Show your PHP debug/Xdebug settings PhpStorm. Maybe something is there.

I didn't change anything with symlinks in Xdebug, mostly, because it never dealt with symlinks but only uses what the OS reports a file is. Also, since when does Windows have symlinks?

"Also, since when does Windows have symlinks?" Windows 10 at least -- native mklink command or using "Link Shell Extension".

@LazyOne, I have added more details including two log files that show the xdebug settings in use at execution. The PhpStorm debug settings are the defaults I believe and don't change between either xdebug environment.


What line does not trigger -- 110 or 113? Maybe there is something in the source file (a breakpoint on a multi-line statement?) that can lead to the PHP or Xdebug do act differently?  2) If you have any watches or other breakpoints -- try clearing them all and see if that will make any difference (I doubt it will do anything here, just a thought)


Other than that: I personally cannot make any better ideas from that. need more context -- maybe if I see that in action with my own eyes I may spot something.


The line # 100 is the one not triggered in xdebug 3.3. Each break is on a simple statement. 2) I cleared all other breakpoints a couple of days ago so I only have the two in the above logs, #100 and #113.


@LazyOne, If you want to take a look, terry@domain in my profile.

So far -- path mappings is my best guess (as far as I understand your setup). But if exactly the same IDE settings work with 3.2 and do not with 3.3... odd.

BTW / on related note: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-600

@LazyOne Thanks for your interest in this issue. I have had to put this on the back burner last week to do some paid work. I have read the Jetbrains link(s) and it does contain the same symptoms but is quite old, however I couldn't see what the change was made six hours ago.

As my simple test shows Xdebug 3.3.0 and symlinks do work as expected but in the more complex applications something is different and the issue arises. Looking at the Changelog for Xdebug 3.3.0 I can see a couple changes to improve/optimise Step Debugging that may have introduced some inadvertent consequences that show up as this issue I am having. https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/pull/915. It would be interesting to test a Xdebug 3.3 module without the optimisation changes applied to see if I am looking in the right area.

@Irata " I have read the Jetbrains link(s) and it does contain the same symptoms but is quite old, however I couldn't see what the change was made six hours ago" It was linked to another partially related ticket (symlinks handling for Java debugging and treating such files as the same).

You see, from the IDE side of things, the IDE uses paths as is. And when you have Path Mappings in use, it translates from one to another. The file where breakpoint does not work, it is technically outside of the project. I'm not sure if the IDE can even map it (unless that path is referenced via IDE's Include Path or something. At the same time -- Xdebug uses the path that PHP reports (normally it's the final/resolved path). So when they do not match -- breakpoint cannot be hit. But if everything is exactly the same and only diff is in Xdebug versions... then I do not know...
